# AJAX & JSON not working, no error or success handlers

Tags: php, ajax, json, magento

I have some code which I plan on adding into a Magento store, once I have made it work on a test page, but unfortunately it isn't working on the test page.

The Javascript is as follows:

```
function plusAddToCart(qty_textbox_id, prodID, highlight_div_id){
var qty = document.getElementById(qty_textbox_id).value;
qty = parseInt(qty) + 1;
document.getElementById(qty_textbox_id).value = qty;
 if(qty==0){
     $(highlight_div_id).style.backgroundColor = "#f7e9f4";
 }else{
     $(highlight_div_id).style.backgroundColor = "#ebcde5";
 }

 $.ajax({                                      
  url: "addtocart.php",
  data: "prodID="+prodID,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    alert("DONE");
  }
});
}
</script>

<div style="width:70px; margin:9px auto 0 auto;">
   <input type='button' name='plus' onclick='plusAddToCart("qty1", "693", "product_highlight_693");' id="plus" class="cart-plus-minus" value='+'/>
   <input name="qty" type="text" id="qty0" readonly="readonly" maxlength="5" value="0" class="quantity-box" />
</div>
```

PHP:

```
 header("Content-Type: text/html");

 require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
 Mage::app("default"); 
 Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend")); 
 $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session"); 

 $userData=Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()->getData(); 
 $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
 $yourProId = $_POST['prodID']; 
 $qty=1; 
 $params = array( 'product' => $yourProId, 'related_product' => null, 'qty' => $qty );
 $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product(); 
 $product->load($yourProId); 
 $cart->addProduct($product, $params); 
 $cart->save(); 
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true); 
 $message = ('Your cart has been updated successfully.'); 
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($message);
```

Can anybody see a reason why this wouldn't work??

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. I don't see an error handler in your code, are you using one? Does the JavaScript console show any problems?

Comment: Install firebug extension in firefox and tell 
what did you see in response of firebug console.......................

Comment: Checked my firebug console and got no errors, warnings or info. You will also have to excuse me if I am a little 'slow' as I am pretty much a PHP developer and am not very knowledgable on AJAX & JSON. Thanks.

Comment: Chrome has Network tab that shows you the data coming from the URL requested by $.ajax, Firebug probably has something similar. Why don't you look at that to check what your server responded with?

Answer (score 3):

The first step would be to add an error handler to your AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    url: "addtocart.php",
    data: "prodID="+prodID,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("DONE");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Not done - ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
    }
}
```

This should give you a better indication of any problems.

**Update**

In your specific case, I think the problem is a combination of:

1. Setting the response dataType to 'JSON'
2. The web service doesn't return any content

I think the request may succeed, but when jQuery attempts to parse the JSON, the empty response cannot be parsed. If you change `dataType` to `text` you may avoid this problem as it won't attempt any parsing.

Comment: It has! It now works on my test page but not on my Magento page. On my Magento I get an error alert box but no actual textStatus or errorThrown.

Comment: I notice you have Firebug - can you open the "Net" tab before the request is made and see if a request is shown in this tab (you will see it under "All" or "XHR" panels in the "Net" tab.

Comment: Yes I receive one one POST linking to my addtocart.php. Status is 200 OK.

Comment: And you get no "Done" message?

Comment: Nope, I get the error message but with no explanation as to why: Not done - error

Comment: That's very odd - is it online somewhere I could look at it in practice?

Comment: Yes of course. I have sent the link via the contact form on your website. (Not sure how to PM on this as I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow, haha). Thanks very much.

Comment: Been working on the code to try and get a fix but still nothing :( Do you have any further ideas on this?

Comment: If you inspect the XMLHttpRequest object on error, the status is "0" and the statusText is "error", so jQuery thinks there is an error even though I can see the HTTP response is 200 OK. I don't know why this is though.

Comment: Update: I have been playing with the code all day today and after changing the async to false I have received a more in depth error: Not done - error [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: <MY URL>/js/jQuery/jquery1.8.2.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 2"  data: no]

does this help?

Comment: Finger in the air time. Can you try returning something in your response - even if it is just "Done" - I am interested in seeing if the zero- length response body is the issue.

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example of how to send through a response? Apologies for my lack of knowledge but I really have been thrown in at the deep end with AJAX :(

Comment: In your PHP page, stick: echo 'Done'; at the end.

Comment: Thanks, still an error but a different one this time!
Not done - error Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101